# Express req.session is set and then empty when trying to POST

Tags: node.js, express, session, passport.js

I have a MERN stack blog app that I'm making as a learning exercise. I'm relatively comfortable on the front end but have limited experience in node. I'm adding authentification after following a couple tutorials to get this far. I'm using passport.js as a framework to make a request to Google, get back an id and save as session info. However, after logging in, req.session is empty when making a post request, even though I can see a cookie in the dev tools.

I'm using bcrypt's hash to obscure the actual id, but that may not be best practice.

in blogAuth.js: req.session is defined.

`bcrypt.hash(req.user._id.toString(), saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
 req.session.user = hash; 
//session is set here. 
console.log(req.session); res.redirect(`http://localhost:8080/articles/loggedIn`);
});`

but in api/articles.js: req.session is empty

`router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
 const { body } = req; 
// session is empty here. Why? 
console.log(`Session user, ${req.session.user}`); 
console.log(req.session);`

I have tried:

- Including proxy in the client package.json:
  [express req.session empty with cookie-session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803692/express-req-session-empty-with-cookie-session)

  using withCredentials set to true when sending the POST from the
  client:[Node + Express + Passport: req.user Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434893/node-express-passport-req-user-undefined?noredirect=1&lq=1)

  Rearranging the order of middleware: Routes must always come
  afterward, but I feel like I'm doing this blindly and it usually results in an error

Here's some of the relevant files:

Server side:
- [app.js](https://github.com/nodes777/blog-server/blob/betterorg/server/app.js)
- [blogAuth.js](https://github.com/nodes777/blog-server/blob/betterorg/server/routes/auth/blogAuth.js)
- [passport.js](https://github.com/nodes777/blog-server/blob/betterorg/server/config/passport.js)
- [api/articles.js](https://github.com/nodes777/blog-server/blob/betterorg/server/routes/api/articles.js)

Client side:
- [the POST req](https://github.com/nodes777/blog-server/blob/betterorg/client/src/containers/ArticlesForm/ArticlesForm.js)

[Entire project](https://github.com/nodes777/blog-server/tree/betterorg)

I believe this is an issue with ordering. What is a good way to ensure that I order my middleware correctly? Or if the order looks correct, where else could this issue becoming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `cookie-session` as well as `express-session`. Since both of them will try to control the fate of `req.session` object, you will end up with empty session always.

Just remove one of them, and your session will be persisted.

Comment: And its as simple as that! Thank you so much, this is has been a road block for me for a couple days. Thanks again!